# how to stop function save in jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When Save button clicked, I want to make sure date exist or not.

I tried to use return false , `e.stopPropagation()` , `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` and none of those works to stop execute `saveEvent`. As you can see in my example, button save  will always be executed. I want to stop that stop the `SaveEvent` . Could you help?

```
       $('#btnSave').click(function () {

                var StartDate = $('#txtStart').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/Checkdate",
                    data: '{StartDate: "' + StartDate + '" }',

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var message = $("#message");
                        if (response) {
                            //Email available.
                            message.css("color", "green");
                            message.html(" date is not exist ");
                        }
                        else {
                            message.css("color", "red");
                            message.html("date existe ");
                            alert('date existe');

                            return;

                        }

                    }
                });


         var data = {

                    EventID: $('#hdEventID').val(),
                    EventTitle: $('#txtSubject').val().trim(),
                    StartDate: $('#txtStart').val().trim(),
                    EndDate: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') ? null : $('#txtEnd').val().trim(),
                    EventDescription: $('#txtDescription').val(),
                    ThemeColor: $('#ddThemeColor').val(),
                    IsFullDay: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked')
                }

                    SaveEvent(data);



                // call function for submit data to the server
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `preventDefault` like this to prevent the default behavior of elements.

Change your above 2 lines to like this.

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSave',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: i used before but no succes

Comment: @aymenbenhassine I've updated my answer check it once

Answer (score 0):

The  call to SaveEvent needs to be inside the `if (response) {` block inside your "success" callback by the looks of it.

It seems that is the place where you verify the status of the date, so that should also be the place where you run the Save command.